# IE6 breaks flow of box (divs)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I've tried various things but the boxes on the right have a spacing issue in IE6.

Seen [here](http://dev.missionmedia.net/justkidsmaryland/)

Anyone have an idea whats causing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to set line-height:0px and font-size:1px for any spacing elements such as content-2nd-box-top which have no text in them and are purely meant to display images.  Alternatively explicitly setting the div size and overflow:hidden may help.

Internet Explorer 6 frequently forces the size of a div to expand to the size of its content which can cause the white space you see over "About the Just Kids Partnership" and other section headers.

I also noticed a typo in your html.  One of your < h2 > tags is missing the right pointy bracket.

(minus spaces)
< h2The Just Kids Report< /h2 >

I may be talking about a different defect than you bring up, but I only have adobe browser labs on this computer, and the most prominent problem I noticed was not on the right, but the section headers much further down on the page.